# How to make scalded (clotted) cream?

Tags: cream, clotted-cream

I can't buy clotted cream in New Zealand, so I'd love to learn how to make it. I have a friend who can provide raw milk.

What's the technique?

Answer (score 8):

You need fresh, creamy raw milk to start with. Pour it into a wide, shallow pan and leave overnight for the cream to separate out.

When ready, heat the milk, very, very gently for about an hour. It should never come anywhere near boiling. Leave overnight again, then you can just scoop the cream off the top.

Comment: Gotta try this, I haven't had clotted cream in eons! :(